# Twitter Bootstrap + Rails, how do you integrate and modify it?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap-3, twitter-bootstrap-rails

How do you customize something like Twitter Bootstrap in a Rails 3.2 app? I have the gem ('bootstrap-sass 3.0.3.0') already. Do I just get a copy of the Sass files and not use the gem at all? I feel like I am missing something here because I have begun to put !important in the CSS of my code. (I'm just trying to change the color of the navbar into a gradient.)

Is there also a way to not use the entire framework? I feel like I don't use some of the components anyway (both CSS and JS).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your `app/asssets/stylesheets/application.sass`

```
$brand-primary: #829F21 !default
$brand-success: #771965 !default
$brand-warning: #A69E22 !default
$brand-danger:  #d9534f !default
$brand-info:    #5bc0de !default
@import "bootstrap"
```

list of variables https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_variables.scss

important thing is to include those variables before you import bootstrap

if you want to import only parts of bootstrap than (like described on the [Readme page](https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass)) include only parts you want

e.g. in `app/assets/javascript/application.js` :

```
//= require bootstrap/scrollspy
//= require bootstrap/modal
//= require bootstrap/dropdown
```

Comment: Man you know what I just had a stupid error, when I was copying the prototype code I copied an older version of _variables.scss, so it was already working. But your answer pushed me in the right direction. Does this apply for the same things such as the jumbotron or other bootstrap CSS components?

Comment: hey dude, don't copy the prototype code, just add `gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.0.3.0'` to your Gemfile run bundle install, then  just add the `@import "bootstrap` into `app/assets/stylesheets/application.sass` (don't forget to remove the app/assets/stylesheets/application.css`) add variables in front of that line,  restart server and done... should just work :)

Comment: yep, thanks man. I was just wondering if people actually copied the entire code in sometimes, and ignore the gem. apparently not

Answer (score 0):

It's just an error on my part. I just didn't copy my code for the static site prototype I built, and I had a copy of _variables.scss in my Rails app. The more you know... T_T